# How to make a Maven release faster?

Tags: maven, jenkins, release

Our build system is pretty stable and consists of Maven with Nexus and Jenkins for CI. As long as we're developing (with SNAPSHOTs), everything is fine, but the release always takes too long.

That's why I wonder how you guys are doing your releases... Especially with Continuous Deployment around the corner.

### Our build system

We have three hierarchical parent POMs:

- The "build" parent which defines the plugins and their configuration.
- The "external versions" parent, which defines the external artifacts and their versions, to keep them under control.
- The "internal versions" parent, which defines our own artifacts and their versions.

Then we have the usual utility project, other base projects etc. etc. They are used as SNAPSHOT dependencies during development.

### Our release

When the time comes for a release, the project's lead developer creates a branch in the SCM and switches to the next SNAPSHOT on the SCM's head.

The build team then continues work on all those branches, to release the POMs and projects.

Basically, we have to release hierarchically, in order to be sure that the released components are used. This means that we first release the three parent POMs and then start bottom-up: Release the utility project, then the base project, which uses the utility project, then some other project that uses both utility and base projects and so on.

This is a process that we have to do by hand. As far as I know, there's no tool that can automate this, right?

In order to update the "internal versions" POM after a project has been released, an automatic update of that POM is done using the Versions Plugin (a life saver!). This means: Release the project into Nexus, then make sure that all other projects being released now use that released version.

Finally, when every project has been released and can be found in Nexus, we build the EARs to deploy with those released artifacts and hand the EARs over to the operations people.

All in all, this takes around one day for every release, which seems like a lot of wasted time. Also, we have a mixture of plain Maven, shell scripts (which use our build utility classes and also Maven) and Jenkins as a UI (the release plugin).

That's why I'm asking you: **What can we do better and faster? How do you release your software?**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two options. First, consider bringing everything together under a single Maven build. If those modules are always released simultaneously then versioning and tracking them separately may not be worthwhile.

> Also, we have a mixture of plain Maven, shell scripts

Bringing this under a single build would require you to integrate these shell scripts into the Maven lifecycle.

Alternatively, if your build is complex enough, consider automating it outside Maven. Any steps you have now should be incorporated into a single shell script.

> This is a process that we have to do by hand. As far as I know, there's no tool that can automate this, right?

A script that knows about your project could make the appropriate checks and `versions:set` invocations.

Bringing everything together under a single automated script is likely to get the build time down to less than a day; if it's still that long then you can see which stages need to be sped up for continuous delivery.